# Fluent nHibernate - Mapping Children with Composite Keys Yielding Null References

Tags: c#, fluent-nhibernate, composite-key

Given a simple parent -> child (CK,CK) setup like this .. I am having trouble with adding a new child object and it getting the parent reference. So I would add the object in such a way ..

```
var parent = new Parent{
  Children = new List<Child>{
   new Child{
     Other = otherReference
   }
  }
};
```

Or even adding it using the `Add()` method...

> parent.Children.Add(new Child { Other = other });

The reference to the `Parent` does not get pushed through. It just ends up as a null property. I get the following exception.

> {"Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'ParentId', table 'mssql_test.Children'; column does not allow nulls. INSERT fails.\r\nThe statement has been terminated."}

I **can** do this ...

```
new Child { 
   Parent = parentReference,
   Other = otherReference
}
```

But that seems a bit redundant. My understanding is that it should be able to infer the reference by itself. If this is not possible, perhaps I am just misunderstanding. Can anyone help me? I have an outline of my code below.

### Classes

```
class Parent {
  int Id { get; set; }
  IList<Child> Children { get; set; }
}
class Other {
  int Id { get; set; }
}
class Child {
  Parent Parent { get; set; }
  Other Other { get; set; }
  // other properties
}
```

### Mapping

```
 ChildMap() {
      CompositeId()
        .KeyReference(x => x.Parent, "ParentId")
        .KeyReference(x => x.Other, "OtherId");
    }

    ParentMap(){
     HasManyToMany(x => x.Children)
                    .AsBag()
                    .ChildKeyColumns.Add(new[] { "ParentId", "OtherId" })
                    .Inverse()
                    .Cascade.All())
                    .Table("[Test]");
}
```

Comment: This sample helped. I over-complicated my mapping and accidentally mapped the keys twice, resulting in the error: Invalid Index n for this SqlParameterCollection with Count=n” OR “foreign key cannot be null”

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @KeithS points out the problem is that you have mapped the Child collection as HasManyToMany when it should be HasMany. Here is how the mapping should look:

```
  ChildMap() {
      CompositeId() //This is is good
        .KeyReference(x => x.Parent, "ParentId")
        .KeyReference(x => x.Other, "OtherId");
  }

  ParentMap(){ //This is the fix
        HasMany(c => c.Children)
          .Inverse()
          .Cascade.All()
          .KeyColumn("ParentId") //Not needed if Parent Id prop maps to ParentId col
          .Table("[Test]");
  }
```

Comment: I still get the exception `{"Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'ParentId', table 'mssql_test.Children'; column does not allow nulls. INSERT fails.\r\nThe statement has been terminated."}`

Comment: If you haven't tried the mapping without the KeyColumn, give that a try. If still no-go then add some debug code to run before the Session flush or is closed to verify the Parent property of the Child object is not null. If it is not null and you get the SQL exception then the problem is likely in the NH mapping.

Comment: Yes, the Parent Property shows as null. The only way to get it to work is to manually assign it every time. It does this whether I define the KeyColumn or not.

Comment: You can try to force loading of the Children collection in the Parent by adding .Not.LazyLoad() after the .Inverse() in the Parent HasMany mapping. This should force populating each Child object and NHibernate should set the Parent property correctly with existing Child objects for that Parent. Of course, you do have to add new Child instances manually by adding them to the Children collection.

Comment: A really good thought,but no, that did not work either. I guess the only possible way to do this is to create the Parent, save it, then create the child and associate it manually? I really thought nHibernate was more advanced than that by now... it kind of disappointed me that something so needed is so cumbersome.

Comment: You shouldn't save the Parent first. The logic flow should be this: create Parent instance; do initialization logic; for each Child instance, initialize and **manually assign** the Parent property; complete Parent processing; finally Flush or close the session. NHibernate will first save the Parent to the database and assign the new primary key value to the Id property. Next it will save each Child instance to the database using the already assigned reference Id. Check this: http://blogs.hibernatingrhinos.com/nhibernate/archive/2008/08/15/a-fluent-interface-to-nhibernate-part-3-mapping.aspx

Comment: Thank you. I had hoped to avoid manually assigning it, but I guess it just isn't possible.

Answer (score 0):

You are not mapping the Parent as a property of the Child. NHibernate (and FluentNH) only map what you tell them to; you could have a dozen fields on your object, but if you only map one of them, that's all NH will provide when it hydrates an instance for you. You should include a "References" method to the Parent in your mapping, specifying the Parent's key field as the FK reference. That should give you the "backreference" you have in your object hierarchy.

Also, it looks like instead of a many-to-many on the Parent side, you should have just a one-to-many (using HasMany). Parents can have many Children, but a Child has one and only one Parent. ManyToMany may work, but it creates a redundant cross-reference table in between Parent and Child.

Comment: Could you cite an example? I am a little confused.

Comment: I tried adding the `References(x => x.Parent).ForeignKey("Id");` to the ChildMap class and it did not change anything.

Comment: On the Child map, the Parent reference is already established by ".KeyReference(x => x.Parent, "ParentId")" so References(...) isn't needed.