# nhibernate: using parts of the compositeId in a ManyToOne Property

Tags: nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

I have a tablestructure like this:

```
Table entity
(
    otherEntity_id  int  // primarykey
    id              int  // primarykey

    parent_id       int
)
```

and class

```
public class Entity
{
    public OtherEntity Other { get; set; }
    // simple int to discriminate different Entity for the same OtherEntity
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public Entity Parent { get; set; }
}
```

is it possible to map this to the class Entity?  (if yes how)

the following throws on save, because there are not enough columns in the dbcommand, one is used twice:

```
        CompositeId()
            .KeyReference(e => e.Other, "otherEntity_id")
            .KeyProperty(e => e.Id, "id")

        References(e => e.Parent).Columns("otherEntity_id", "parent_id");
```

It doesnt matter using xml or fluent.

Edit:
without the reference mapped no error, with reference mapped following error
(i had this error several times, everytime when i have more values than mapped columns):

```
System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException : Der Index lag außerhalb des Bereichs. Er muss nicht negativ und kleiner als die Auflistung sein.
Parametername: index
   bei System.ThrowHelper.ThrowArgumentOutOfRangeException(ExceptionArgument argument, ExceptionResource resource)
   bei System.ThrowHelper.ThrowArgumentOutOfRangeException()
   bei System.Collections.Generic.List`1.get_Item(Int32 index)
   bei Npgsql.NpgsqlParameterCollection.get_Item(Int32 index)
   bei Npgsql.NpgsqlParameterCollection.GetParameter(Int32 index)
   bei System.Data.Common.DbParameterCollection.System.Collections.IList.get_Item(Int32 index)
   bei NHibernate.Type.Int16Type.Set(IDbCommand rs, Object value, Int32 index)
   bei NHibernate.Type.NullableType.NullSafeSet(IDbCommand cmd, Object value, Int32 index)
   bei NHibernate.Type.NullableType.NullSafeSet(IDbCommand st, Object value, Int32 index, ISessionImplementor session)
   bei NHibernate.Type.ComponentType.NullSafeSet(IDbCommand st, Object value, Int32 begin, ISessionImplementor session)
   bei NHibernate.Persister.Entity.AbstractEntityPersister.Dehydrate(Object id, Object[] fields, Object rowId, Boolean[] includeProperty, Boolean[][] includeColumns, Int32 table, IDbCommand statement, ISessionImplementor session, Int32 index)
   bei NHibernate.Persister.Entity.AbstractEntityPersister.Insert(Object id, Object[] fields, Boolean[] notNull, Int32 j, SqlCommandInfo sql, Object obj, ISessionImplementor session)
   bei NHibernate.Persister.Entity.AbstractEntityPersister.Insert(Object id, Object[] fields, Object obj, ISessionImplementor session)
   bei NHibernate.Action.EntityInsertAction.Execute()
   bei NHibernate.Engine.ActionQueue.Execute(IExecutable executable)
   bei NHibernate.Engine.ActionQueue.ExecuteActions(IList list)
   bei NHibernate.Engine.ActionQueue.ExecuteActions()
   bei NHibernate.Event.Default.AbstractFlushingEventListener.PerformExecutions(IEventSource session)
   bei NHibernate.Event.Default.DefaultFlushEventListener.OnFlush(FlushEvent event)
   bei NHibernate.Impl.SessionImpl.Flush()
```

testcode

```
        var e1 = new Entity { Id = 2, Other = other };
        var e2 = new Entity { Id = 3, Other = other, Parent = e1 };

        Session.Save(e1);
        Session.Save(e2);
        Session.Flush();    // throws here
        Session.Clear();

        var key = new Entity { Id = e2.Id, Other = e2.Other };

        var loaded = Session.Get<Entity>(key);
```

Edit:

if it's not possible could please someone tell me?

Comment: I see don't where the many to one relationship exists from an NHibernate point of view. The Entity class can contain exactly one Parent reference and exactly one OtherEntity reference. Could you please provide information [along the lines of this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5900383/fluent-nhibernate-mapping-children-with-composite-keys-yielding-null-references) to clarify the relationships.

Comment: OtherEntity has a collection of entities and each entity has a parent entity if it is derived from it. to reference (manytoone) its parent, entity has to hold the primary key of Entity (otherEntity_id, id) but in the table of entity it uses its own primary key part otherEntity_id instead of another column parent_otherEntity_id.

Comment: Why are you using composite id?

Comment: @Jakub Linhart because id alone is not unique. it's only unique per otherEntity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I still haven't found a solution and mapped changed my model to:

```
public class Entity
{
    public OtherEntity Other { get; set; }
    // simple int to discriminate different Entity for the same OtherEntity
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public int ParentId { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are referencing the same column above twice (otherEntity_id) I've seen mappings like this to avoid this sort of error:

```
References(e => e.Parent).Columns("otherEntity_id", "parent_id")
    .Not.Update()
    .Not.Insert();
```

Also when you are running into a problem it is always helpful to show the full error message you are running into.

Comment: nice idea, unfortunatly this prevents both columns from being inserted (checked the sql) but i need only the first one being ignored