# Reference entity with composite id

Tags: nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, foreign-keys, fluent-nhibernate-mapping

Both entity A & B's id are:

```
CompositeId().KeyProperty(x => x.Id).KeyProperty(x => x.Type);
```

While entity B should Reference entity A (it has a property "A" of type A). I tried:

```
References(x => x.A).Columns("AId", "Type");
```

Which gave me IndexOutOfRange exception when trying to insert, the reason was that the "Type" property was mapped twice. So I added:

```
References(x => x.A).Columns("AId", "Type").Not.Update().Not.Insert();
```

Which causes AId to always be NULL because it's defined not to be inserted. I want it to be insertable and updatable, while "Type" not to be. How can I do this?

Comment: i have the same problem but havent found a solution yet: http://stackoverflow.com/q/6047926/671619

Comment: `Which causes AId to always be NULL because it's defined not to be inserted. I want it to be insertable and updatable, while "Type" not to be. How can I do this?`  Can you not insert/update this entity separately?

Comment: What do you mean insert the entity separately? You want me to make a different insert query to the DB that updates the column AId?