# Fluent NHibernate Self Reference Table With Composite Key

Tags: fluent-nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate-mapping

I just want to know if this is possible to do with fluent nhibernate.

I got a self reference table in my database.

```
Table Service
{
int Season (PK) (FK)
int Service_No (PK)
int ParentService_No (FK)
}
```

The table has a composite key as Season and Service_No, and Foreign Key for Self Reference as Season and ParentService_No

I try to create a collection property called ChildServices in my Service Class as many to many relations.

```
HasManyToMany(x => x.ChildServices )
.Table("SERVICE")
.Access.Property()
.AsBag()
.Cascade.SaveUpdate()
.LazyLoad()
.Generic()
.ParentKeyColumns.Add("SEASON")
.ParentKeyColumns.Add("SERVICE_NO")
.ChildKeyColumns.Add("SEASON")
.ChildKeyColumns.Add("P_SERVICE_NO");
```

If I use above mapping, it will throw my exception saying Repeated column in mapping for collection: Service.ChildServices column: SEASON

How can I do this? Is this a limitation of fluent nhibernate?

Thanks for answering my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is a limitation of NHibernate. You can not use one column for two different things for example in your case primary key and foreign key. [see my question on the same subject](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6047926/671619)

you could try to guess NHibernate's generated alias and use the `ParentService_No` column as foreignkey and a where condition with the alias on the service_no